# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidebar is not a function

Tags: jquery, laravel, semantic-ui

I am building a layout to a laravel application and i'm having some errors i cannot understand.
The sidebar and other components are not being loaded. i get the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).sidebar is not a function`. this happens to other components (dropdown / accordion), the dropdown and accordion error are showed in chrome dev tools as soon the page loads, the sidebar error only shows if i try to open the sidebar.

The reason i have included laravel in the tags is because i have tested exactly the same layout in another folder (outside the laravel structure) and it works. i am not sure if it is the way laravel processes the views.

The scripts i am loading are, in `<head>`:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script scr="{{ asset('semantic/semantic.min.js') }}"></script>
```

at the end of `<body>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#menu').click(function(){
            $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
        }); 
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('.ui.accordion').accordion({
            selector: {
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".ui.dropdown").dropdown({
            allowCategorySelection: true,
            transition: "fade up",
            context: 'sidebar',
            on: "click"
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the code of the sidebar:

```
<div class="ui sidebar vertical left inverted menu" id="sidebar">
        <br>
        <div class="ui inverted accordion" style="padding-left: 10px">
            <div class="title item">Tasks<i class="dropdown icon"></i></div>
            <div class="content">
                <a class="small item" href="">My Tasks<i class="ui tasks icon"></i></a>
                <a class="small item" href="">Task Overview<i class="ui globe icon"></i> </a>
                <a class="small item" href="">New task<i class="ui plus icon"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="ui inverted large accordion" style="padding-left: 10px">
            <div class="title item">Reports<i class="dropdown icon"></i></div>
            <div class="content">
                <a class="item" href="">Reports<i class="bar chart icon"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

i have tried using different versions of jquery and changing the loading order of jquery and semantic.js.

There are other questions similar to this one in stackoverflow, i have tried them, but keep getting the same errors

thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the complete path of this folder?

Comment: See the source code in browser and check if the jQuery has been loaded or not.

Comment: @Danial Sandeelo, js are in the folder ../public/js, semantic. js is in ../public/semantic. if i check the code of the loaded page it shows this for the js: <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei, if i check the code of the loaded page it shows this for the js: <script src="localhost:8000/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>, so i presume it has been loaded

Comment: is it named `semantic.js` or `semantic.min.js`?

Comment: @CaddyDZ, i have both semantic.js and semantic.min.js in the same folder. i am not an experienced developer, so correct me if i am wrong, but i think i can use any of them

Comment: Your code should work. 
Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ydepj9v/2

Comment: @CaddyDZ, i've tried it in a separate folder and it works. i don't know if anything changed in laravel 5.8 that may have changed the way views are processed.

Comment: No this has nothing to do with Laravel, do other Semantic UI components work?

Comment: i was only working in the layout and have not tried the components in the content section. and NO, any component that has jquery like dropdown or accordion does not work. but the css is being loaded correctly